# Remove Action Listner from a jline ConsoleReader

Tags: java, console, jline

I am using the [jline.ConsoleReader](http://jline.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jline/ConsoleReader.html) provided and adding an ActionListner for a key (say pressing 'q') using

```
q. addTriggerAction('q', new ActionListener(){ System.out.println("Triggered"); });
```

However after a certain time I need to stop triggering the action and remove the listener. How can I do that? I might need to add a new different ActionListener to the same action later

Comment: You'd need a reference to the original `ActionListener`, instead of create an inline class like you are, create an `ActionListener` and assign it an instance variable you can reference later

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you for the answer. But I didn't quite get what you meant. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Create an instance field of `ActionListener`, `private ActionListener triggerActionListener;`, assign a reference of `ActionListener` to it `triggerActionListener = new ActionListener(){ System.out.println("Triggered"); };`, add this to the `q`, `q. addTriggerAction('q', triggerActionListener);`, when needed, use this reference to remove it...

Comment: Thank you very much. I think this answers my question

Comment: @MadProgrammer well that didn't solve my problem. How can I set the action to null or change it even if I have a reference? (Without creating a new ActionListener object that is ) I edited my question too

Comment: Can't you do something like `q.removeActionListener(triggerActionListener)` ?

Comment: Have you tried `q.addTriggerAction('q', null)`?

Comment: there's no removeActionListner method so that's why I asked the question. And I think setting it to null should work :) Thanks